# Tensorflow Graph, Session management for cross-validation

Tags: session, tensorflow, graph, cross-validation

What is the proper way of managing (initialize, close, reset) sessions and graphs when implementing cross-validation in Tensorflow?

Should I reset the session and graph for each fold, or is it better/possible to keep a single session throughout the entire process? One advantage of doing the latter is that resources are bound throughout the entire process, e.g. preventing that some unrelated process running on the same machine claims the GPU while I am processing/saving results in-between folds.

Would it be enough to keep the same graph/session and simply re-initialize the parameters by:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # define model here #
        for fold in folds:
            init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
            sess.run(init)
            # train model here #
```

Also, I guess that ideally summaries (and possibly checkpoints?) should be kept separately for each fold.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a session and use it as long as I require, this is much better in terms of speed and performance, and later if we close the session, then we can claim the resources back. Moreover, if we use allow_growth config to True, then other programs will also be able to use the resources.

Comment: Is it possible to simply re-initialize the parameters (see edited question above), or am I missing something?